# Update the label of Google Cloud Function using API in Python

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-functions, label

I am trying to add labels in the cloud function using API

```py
class MemoryCache(Cache):
    _CACHE = {}
    def get(self, url):
        return MemoryCache._CACHE.get(url)
    def set(self, url, content):
        MemoryCache._CACHE[url] = content

    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes)
    service = build('cloudfunctions', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache=MemoryCache())
    name='projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/function-1'
    result_call = service.projects().locations().functions().get(name=name, x__xgafv=None).execute()
    print(result_call)

    updateMask = ['labels']
    body = {'labels': {'type': 'testing'}}
    result = service.projects().locations().functions().patch(name=name, updateMask=updateMask,
    body=body,
    x__xgafv=None).execute()
```

This code throws an error the format of `updateMask` is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/patch#query-parameters), `updateMask` requires a **String** input however, you're passing a **List** and that explains why the format is incorrect.

The solution is to change the value of updateMask to String. For example:

```
updateMask = 'labels'
```

If there's a case where you wish to you have multiple values, then it must to be on a single string separated with a comma.